# comint-mode + vagrant

Tags: spacemacs, ruby-mode, ruby, docker

Disclaimer: Pretty new to Emacs and running Spacemacs, have no idea what I'm doing with elisp.

We run all our projects under vagrant, so I'm interested in getting some things, such as `inf-ruby-mode` consoles, to `ssh` into my vagrant box before running their commands. In particular, I'm currently looking at the `run-ruby` [function](https://github.com/nonsequitur/inf-ruby/blob/master/inf-ruby.el#L303) right now.

I decided that aliasing `bundle` to run under the ssh box would do this, so I made myself an eshell alias, but that doesn't seem to get loaded in `comint-mode`, which I'm fairly certain is how such commands are run.

Another approach might be to have a `comint` hook which first SSH's into the box before running another command.

Is this possible? Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

I added the `docker` tag to this because the workflow can be quite similar, and there's no existing `vagrant` tag.

Comment: As for docker: I have a bash script that I set as an executable which is run by `shell` command. The script does roughly `docker exec -ti some_container bash`, which then runs interactive shell inside the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use next function to run rails console on remote host.

It seems that run-ruby doesn't care how REPL is started, so I pass it an ssh command. Most important part is the command itself:

- `-t` for pseudo-terminal mode, without it repl won't work;
- `bash --login` to get usual shell (for `rbenv`, `rvm` or other stuff that initialised on shell startup). If you use zsh, you can share init code somewhere in `.profile` and add `source $HOME/.profile` to both: `.zshrc` and `.bashrc` ;
- `-c` is a bash option with command to run in single quotes

Also there are `cd` to set working directory and for my case - environment type (production, testing, etc..)

```
(defun rails-console-remote (&optional host &optional path &optional env &optional user-cmd)
  "Call `run-ruby'."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((default-cmd '"bundle exec rails console"))
    (run-ruby
     (format "/usr/bin/ssh -t %s cd %s; /bin/bash --login -c '%s %s'"
             (or host (read-string "host: "))
             (or path (read-string "path: "))
             (if user-cmd
                 user-cmd
               (read-string "rails console: " default-cmd))
             (or env "production")))))
```

P.S.: `&optional` and `(or var (read-string "prompt: "))` to make it more interactive.

Comment: Could you explain your answer in more detail?